# The tags 'listening-comprehension' and 'listening' have been merged

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

**The tags [listening-comprehension](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening-comprehension) and [listening](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening) have been merged.**

---

We currently have tags for both `listening-comprehension` (13 questions) and `listening` (11 questions).

The tag [listening-comprehension](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening-comprehension) currently has the following incorrect (!) tag wiki excerpt:

> a language learning technique that involves listening to an audiobook or other auditory content in an L2 in an effort to improve pronunciation and speech in the L2.

This description is incorrect because (1) listening comprehension is not a technique but an ability and (2) it is about extracting meaning from spoken language (not necessarily from audiobooks) and has nothing to do with improving pronunciation or speech.

The tag [listening](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening) currently has the following tag wiki excerpt:

> Questions related to listening, especially developing and improving listening skills.

This is fine and can easily be tweaked to include listening comprehension.

Some of the questions tagged [listening](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening) are about resources (including radio stations) that one might listen to but don't explicitly mention listening comprehension (or a phrase that comes down to the same thing). Three of the 11 questions tagged [listening](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening) also use the tag `listening-comprehension`. (Three of the 13 questions tagged [listening-comprehenion](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening-comprehenion) also use the tag `listening`.)

Since listening is the wider of the two terms, I propose that we **turn [listening-comprehenion](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening-comprehenion) into a synonym of [listening](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/listening)**. If I don't hear any **objections before 20 January** (2019), i.e. just over two weeks from now, I will proceed with this proposal.

Comment: I think the key question is: Are there questions about listening that are not about listening comprehension?

Comment: @TommiBrander [This quesion](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/3580/800) is about listening as a learning technique rather than strictly about improving listening comprehension.

Comment: FYI, the Community bot keeps bumping this question because of the lack of votes on the answer (which has remained at a score of 0 as a result).

Comment: @V2Blast Perhaps the community bot should stop bumping questions with the tag [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: @Tsundoku: You're welcome to make a request for that on MSE. For now, [the answer to this FAQ on MSE describes the criteria that are currently used to determine which questions are automatically bumped by the Community bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48578/335251).

Answer (score 0):

Going by the natural language meaning of the words, I would understand "listening comprehension" to apply to questions about how to better understand spoken language.

As illustrated in the comments and the post, "listening" is a broader concept; it might include

- listening as a method for learning a language
- listening as a goal or a component of language learning, i.e. listening comprehension (redundant meaning, but having broader and narrower tags is fine, I think)
- listening as an activity might crop up in some other use, as far as I know

I suggest keeping both tags, but

1. fixing the tag wikis
2. retagging questions if necessary, maybe three per day or so; the stack moves slowly and updating questions to give them more attention is not a bad thing.

Comment: How would you fix the [tag:listening] tag wiki? Something along the lines "Questions related to listening that are NOT about improving listening skills"?

Comment: Listening can include improving listening skills. I do not see a problem.